# Call to a member function load() on a non-object when autoloading config files at CodeIgniter 3.0

Tags: php, codeigniter, config, codeigniter-3

I'm working in a small project with CI 3.0. I have set up `/application/config/autoload.php` for autoload app config file as follow:

```
$autoload['config'] = array('myappcfg');
```

Then at controller constructor I'm doing the following:

```
protected $facebookSession;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->facebookSession = FacebookSession::newAppSession(
        $this->config->item( 'facebook_app_id' ),
        $this->config->item( 'facebook_app_secret' )
    );
}
```

But I'm getting this notice:

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice Message: Undefined
>   property: ShareFacebook::$config Filename:
>   controllers/ShareFacebook.php Line Number: 16

```
Backtrace:
    File: /var/www/html/dts/myapp/application/controllers/ShareFacebook.php
        Line: 16
        Function: _error_handler

        File: /var/www/html/dts/myapp/index.php
        Line: 292
        Function: require_once

    Fatal error: Call to a member function load() on a non-object in /var/www/html/dts/myapp/application/controllers/ShareFacebook.php on line 16
```

Can any tell me what I'm doing wrong? Why I can't access `$this->config` at controller if config file is autoloaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well since I've found the solution I will share for others, the problem is the constructor since I was missing inherits from the CI_Controller. In a few words this was missing:

```
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't stated as such so I am assuming that when you tried...

```
protected $facebookSession;

public function __construct()
{
        echo $this->config->item('facebook_app_id');
        echo '<br>';
        echo $this->config->item('facebook_app_secret');

//    $this->facebookSession = FacebookSession::newAppSession(
//        $this->config->item( 'facebook_app_id' ),
//        $this->config->item( 'facebook_app_secret' )
//    );
}
```

You were able to see see the values of the two config items in question!

Update:
So you have the file called myappcfg.php saved under /application/config and the file itself contains something like...

```
<?php
$config['facebook_app_id'] = 'app_id';
$config['facebook_app_secret'] = 'app_secret';
```

Also check the spelling and case of your filenames. It can be as simple as that sometimes.

Comment: I got the same error as before, something is wrong with config files or so on

Comment: You're right about your update, file is in `/application/config/myappcfg.php` and names are right